# My tree seems to be dying or is in shock. I don’t know what to do

Tags: trees

My tree seems to be in trouble it’s just one limb. I had someone cut my yard and they did run up on the root. It’s raised in some places. It’s a camphor tree and it’s about a hundred years old. Otherwise it’s been in very good health. I don’t want to lose the tree. But I don’t know if it’s serious [image]. I can’t seem to load another photo. But the original is already shown

Comment: Well, this is far more than damaging one root.  This looks like chemical damage.

Answer (score 1):

There's a logical fallacy called *post hoc, propter hoc* which basically says "after it, therefore because of it"; just because the root was damaged does not necessarily link that event to the dead limb. In fact it is highly unlikely given that the tree will have many roots supporting it.

The most common problem with Cinnamomum is [verticillium wilt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Verticillium_wilt). Take a look at the wiki page and you will see a picture of an infected tree that rather resembles your own. The only way to know for sure is to take a sample of dying wood and have it tested. You may be able to find a local arborist who has the specialized knowledge to diagnose it for you.